# Removing HTML Text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

Hope everyone is doing well. I am having a really really really stupid problem and googling did not help. I was wondering if you guys could help.

Here is my issue: I can only modify css and jquery i use jquery to modify the html all the time but im running into a weird problem. here is my code.. all of it works except this part.

```
$("#Menu_List")
    .prepend('<i class="fa fa-file-o fa-fw"></i>');
$("#Menu_New")
    .prepend('<i class="fa fa-plus-square-o fa-fw"></i>');
$("#Menu_Wiki")
    .prepend('<i class="fa fa-bars fa-fw"></i>');
$("#Menu_Discuss")
    .prepend('<i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-fw"></i>');
$("#navTopContainer")
    .insertAfter("#belowBanner");
//THE LAST FUNCTION MOVES THE USER OPTION TO THE BOTTOM OF HEADER
$('img.down-arrow-blue').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-fw" style="font-size: 17px;"></i>');

$("#Menu_Help").remove();
$("#Menu_Extras").remove();
$("navTop").remove(&nbsp;|&nbsp;);
```

Here's the problem the last line.... navtop.

i only want it to have one damn line! but there are three

|  |  |

here's the html if it helps.. i can't figure it out

```
<div id="navTop">
<nobr><span id="username">Partner Test <span class="noDisplay" id=
"usertype">(Community)</span></span>&nbsp;<a class="navlink" href=
"default.asp?pg=pgSettings" id="Menu_Settings" onclick=
"return theMgr.showPopup('settingsPopup',this,0,this.offsetHeight + 4,null,true) || KeyManager.browseMenus('navTop') || KeyManager.oMenuBrowser.setElCurrent(this) || KeyManager.browsePopup('settingsPopup');"
title="Update settings and user preferences"><span class="dotted">My
Settings</span><img border="0" class="small-down-arrow-black" src=
"images/clear.gif"></a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a class=
"navlink" href="default.asp?pre=preLogOff" id="Menu_LogInOut" title=
""><span class="underline">Log Off</span></a></nobr>
```

Comment: You need to look for textnodes and remove them....

Comment: Thanks buddy i'm going to look it up!

Comment: Or you can now look at my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the textnodes since it is not wrapped in an element. Than you can find it and replace it with one.

```js
$("#navTop nobr").contents().each(
  function () {
    if (this.nodeType===3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf("|") > -1){
        this.nodeValue = " | ";  
    }
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navTop">
<nobr><span id="username">Partner Test <span class="noDisplay" id=
"usertype">(Community)</span></span>&nbsp;<a class="navlink" href=
"default.asp?pg=pgSettings" id="Menu_Settings" onclick=
"return theMgr.showPopup('settingsPopup',this,0,this.offsetHeight + 4,null,true) || KeyManager.browseMenus('navTop') || KeyManager.oMenuBrowser.setElCurrent(this) || KeyManager.browsePopup('settingsPopup');"
title="Update settings and user preferences"><span class="dotted">My
Settings</span><img border="0" class="small-down-arrow-black" src=
"images/clear.gif"></a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a class=
"navlink" href="default.asp?pre=preLogOff" id="Menu_LogInOut" title=
""><span class="underline">Log Off</span></a></nobr>
```

Comment: your amazing. that was clean as hell!

Comment: Hey can i ask you another question something weird happended when i uploaded the code. Instead of the  | | getting removed it changed this &nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;   to this | | |

Comment: I have no idea why yours did not work so i did it a dirty way. I wrapped the elements in an <a> tag with a class and i wrote another code to delete it and another to append a ' | ' :/